# ReleaseHandleFailed was detected when debugging with MSTest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, visual-studio-debugging

When I run my unit tests in debug mode, I get a recurrent exception like this:

[image]

I click  "Continue" and then the test goes on without any problem. I have to do this around 10 to 15 times per test I want to debug. If I simple RUN the test, I get no exception whatsoever.

The test does well anyway, I click "Continue" on the recurrent exception and the test ends gracefully.

The exception has no stack trace. All the information I can get about it is in that screenshot. Even if I choose to "Copy MDA message to clipboard", it is the same as appears on the screenshoot.

The test is using Entity Framework Code First, and dropping and creating the database each time.

What could be the problem? I am not using any kind of encryption, but the test connects to the SqlServer and do some operations with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: There is not ST, all the information I have is what you see there.

Comment: Click OK.  Debug + Windows + Call Stack.

Comment: The call stack is empty. There is only an entry that says [External Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to disable the warning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx

But I would like to know what is going on.

Cheers.